# Finding an edge that decreases the shortest path from A to B by the most

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Given an undirected graph G with edge weights, a set of candidate edges (length |V| + |E|), and vertices A and B, find the edge that decreases the shortest path from A to B by the most.

For example:

[image]

The candidate edges are the dotted lines. The shortest path from A to B is A -> C -> D -> G -> B (cost 7). But with the edge (D, B), the shortest path is A -> C -> D -> B (cost 6), so the algorithm should return (D, B).

I came up with a brute force solution O((|V| + |E|)^2 log |V|):

- for each candidate edge:

  - add the edge to the graph
  - run Dijkstra's to find the cost of the shortest path from A to B
  - remove the edge
- return the candidate edge that results in the shortest path

but is there anything better?

Comment: If `n = |V|` and `m = |E|`, Dijkstra's algorithm runs in `O(m + nlogn)` if enhanced with a priority queue such as the Fibonacci heap. Assuming `m >= n` (otherwise the graph is disjoint), the time complexity of your brute force method is `O(m^2 + mnlogn)`. So I am a bit puzzled by the time complexity that you have given in your question.

Answer (score 8):

One approach is:

- Run Dijkstra from A and store distance to each node n in A[n]
- Run Dijkstra from B and store distance to each node n in B[n]
- Loop over each candidate edge.  For an edge with weight w that connects vertices x and y, compare w+A[x]+B[y] and w+A[y]+B[x]

The smaller of w+A[x]+B[y] and w+A[y]+B[x] gives the shortest path between A and B when the candidate edge is used.

Comment: I was puzzled by this answer until I re-read the question and realised that `G` is undirected.

Comment: Even if G were directed, one could still use Dijkstra to compute distances *to* B.